# Buttons in GUI always end up in top left position no matter what I code

Tags: java, user-interface, button, javafx

I had this problem with another GUI of mine, and I can't get it fixed no matter what I do. Followed an example in my book and still end up with the alignment being ignored.

No matter what `setAlignment` I do for Pos, my buttons always end up in the **top left corner** of my GUI.

Tried reorganizing the code, and different positions for `setAlignment`

```
package application;


import javafx.scene.image.*;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.Group;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.scene.shape.*;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.geometry.Pos;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.layout.FlowPane;



public class Game extends Application {
    Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(0, 800, 800, 100);


    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {

        rect.setFill(Color.BLACK);

        Button pushA = new Button("Fight");
        pushA.setOnAction(this::processButtonPressFight);

        Button pushB = new Button("Block");
        pushB.setOnAction(this::processButtonPressFight);

        Button pushC = new Button("Bag");
        pushC.setOnAction(this::processButtonPressFight);

        FlowPane pane = new FlowPane(pushA, pushB, pushC);
        pane.setAlignment(Pos.BASELINE_LEFT);
        pane.setHgap(100);

        Group root = new Group(rect, pane);
        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 800, 900);

        primaryStage.setTitle("Dungeon Crawler Battle!");
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }
    public void processButtonPressFight(ActionEvent event) {

    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

I expect my buttons to be in the baseline left, but get them in the top left.

Comment: What if you try `Pos.BOTTOM_LEFT`?

Comment: Same thing happens with that

Comment: You're wrapping the `FlowPane` in a `Group` which results in the `FlowPane` only growing as large as its preferred size. Try wrapping the `FlowPane` in a layout that will resize its children to fill the available space or setting the `FlowPane` as the root directly.

Comment: Change `Group root = new Group(rect, pane);` to `VBox root = new VBox(rect, pane);` ?

Answer (score 1):

Ah the problem is that you are setting the size of the scene not the pane so since the pane is not the same size it is not filling the whole scene which is why your positions are not changing if you add a border to the pane like so

```
pane.setStyle("-fx-border-color:black; -fx-border-width: 2 2 2 2");
```

You will see how small and where the pane is located once the pane size is changed this should no longer be a problem

To sum up the alignment is not being ignored you just can't see the change because the pane is small